# Turbolinks cause on scroll event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

On my Rails 5 app I have a script that should be fired on the `scroll` event, but for some reason I can't make it work with the turbolinks gem.

My code:

1st attempt:

```
$("#side-block").on("scroll page:load", function(e) {
    console.log("scroll");
}
```

2nd attempt:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#side-block").on("scroll page:load", function(e) {
    console.log("scroll");
  });
});
```

Both with no luck. The script is loaded correctly but `on scroll` is not triggered. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try using event delegation:

```
$(document).on("scroll", "#side-block", function(e) {
    console.log("scroll");
}
```

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads

Comment: It didn't solved my issue, but even though was helpful. Pointed me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to wrong `overflow` property on element. According to jQuery documentation:

> The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents).

Thats why `scroll` event was never triggered.

Moreover I found useful to wrap JS (when using a turbolinks gem) with this code:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
   ...
 });
```

It allowed me to manipulate page elements after page was rendered.